# How to delete multiple entities from GAE datastore by keys

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Google App Engine on localhost. I have 2000 entities of kind `Book` in the Datastore. I want to delete the first 1900 (the keys range from 1 to 1901). How would I do that from the interactive console? I am using `ndb` as opposed to `db`

Maybe there is some sort of range functionality.

For example, I try the following, but nothing happens.

```
from myddb import Book

list= Book.gql("WHERE ID < 193")

for entity in list:
  db.delete(entity)
```

EDIT:

Based on response from @Lipis the following is working

```
from myddb import Book

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

book_keys = Book.query().fetch(keys_only=True)
ndb.delete_multi(book_keys)
```

But that deletes everything. What I need to work is query by `Key` aka `ID` like

```
book_keys = Book.query(Article._Key < 1901).fetch(keys_only=True)
```

Comment: Is ID an attribute of a Book entity explicitly defined in the model or is it the id in ndb which is the equivalent to key_name in the old db?

Comment: instead of db.delete you should use key.delete()

Comment: You sound frustrated. Hang in there. If you find the answer remember to post back. +1

Answer (score 10):

You should use the `ndb.delete_multi()`:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

book_keys = Book.query().fetch(keys_only=True)
ndb.delete_multi(book_keys)
```

You should go through the [NDB Queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries) to see what other options you have and what you can achieve.

Comment: +1 this works. But so far it deletes everything. Do you know how I could specify range? I try `Book.query(Book.id < 19001)` but that's not working.

Comment: Also If I delete by language, it works: `Book.query(Book.language == "english")`. That deletes all entities where language is `english`. Is there a problem with querying on `auto-generated` field? My db has a field, which I specify but which is auto-generated called `id`. Also although I have `id` in my python script, it shows up as `ID` in data viewer. the property is `id = ndb.IntegerProperty()`

Comment: @user1612593 You cannot query by the autogenerated id value which is actually the `key.id()`.. but you could possible query by id. I would avoid naming id my field since it can be confused with the other id. I updated my answer with a link to what you have to go through to understand more

Comment: Thanks for your help. Have you seen my latest edit? I figured that I needed to query by key, which shows up as `ID` on `dataviewer`. Do you know how to query by keys as I show above? I have been trying all sorts of `filters`. So far Nothing.

Comment: How to fetch an entity according to the entity key, like `Ingredient.gql('WHERE Key = :1', self.key).fetch()` but for me it shows ingredient model has no attribute key.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

I have not tested the solution below but test it and let me know.

Also this should help greatly [ndb cheat sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic)

```
q = Book.query(default_options=QueryOptions(keys_only=True))

   if Book.ID < 1901:
      ndb.delete_multi([m.key for m in q.fetch(1900)])
```

Comment: I changed the answer I overlooked that you were wanting to retrieve by ID

Comment: It complains that `Book` has no attribute `all`.

Comment: I am using ndb as opposed to db. I don't know if that matters.

Comment: Yes it does you should have included that in the question.

Comment: I will edit the post. I managed to get a result set using `Book.query()` but the delete portion still does not work.

Comment: +1 all over for helping. It looks like I need to know how to query by key

Comment: Made changes to the above answer let me know if it works or gets you close to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In `ndb you use q = Book.query('query').fetch('number')`

Then, iterate and delete.

Comment: +1 for helping. What I need is to be able to query by key as I post my edit.